# Exported RCP product not starting correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have converted a Kepler-based 3.x RCP application to use the current Eclipse release. At the same time I reconfigured the product definition to use features rather than plugins as it did previously.

Using the product definition from within Eclipse, I have been able to test the application successfully.

I exported the product and I was able to see all of the relevant plugins and features in the target.

However, when I started the application only the splash was shown.

```
!SESSION 2020-06-05 14:52:09.778 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_242
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de
Framework arguments:  -sap r3a -svn https://svnbuild.acme.com/svn/l-svnatf-test -role DEVELOPER
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -sap r3a -data c:\ATF\workspace-DEVELOPER-Test-Feature -svn https://svnbuild.acme.com/svn/l-svnatf-test -role DEVELOPER

!ENTRY com.acme.atf.app 4 0 2020-06-05 14:52:12.029
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.acme.atf.app [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.acme.atf.help

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2020-06-05 14:52:13.684
!MESSAGE Product com.acme.atf.app.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-06-05 14:52:15.012
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon' from bundle '111'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:408)
```

I compared the output with a previous build and noticed that the `configuration/config.ini` previously contained an entry for `osgi.bundles` which was a comprehensive list of all required bundles. The newer version is quite different:

```
#Product Runtime Configuration File
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.product=com.acme.atf.app.product
osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/com.acme.atf.app
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator@1:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
```

(The `bundles.info` file does contain a long list of relevant bundles.)

As a test, I copied the 'old' `config.ini` in to the new target. In this case the application did get further and display my login dialog.

What might be the problem here? My 'help' bundle is certainly present so where does the error come from?

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.acme.atf.app [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.acme.atf.help
```

Or what causes

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
```

Comment: Possibly start levels. Make sure you have the recommended levels configured in the product file

Comment: @greg-449 thanks - that helped to get things going (Product: Configuration->Add recommended...). I still have plugin loading problems but I'll put that in a new question...